# Unlimited precision and specified rounding & scale with string constructor

Tags: c++, scale, rounding, precision, bigdecimal

With Java's [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), it's possible to have unlimited precision and specified rounding & scale with a string constructor.

I've seen GNU's GMP, boost's multiprecision, and [MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org/), but none seem to have theses characteristics.

Can any of them do this?  If so, how?  If not, how can this be done?

Comment: GMP has `explicit mpf_class::mpf_class (const string& s)`, which is defined in gmpxx.h

Comment: @segfault Thank-you segfault!  I am very unsure of how to translate Java's implementation to GMP.  Would you mind showing a quick example of how the equivalent Java and C++ code?  Thank you so very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GMP is designed to have arbitrary precision with support for C++ using the `gmpxx.h` header, and corresponding library. If you're building GMP from scratch, use `--enable-cxx` flag during configure.

To construct an object from `std::string`, simply use the constructor, for example,

```
#include <gmpxx.h>

const std::string longNumber = "12345678901234567890";

mpz_class n(longNumber);
```

More details are available [here](https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-Integers.html)

Comment: Thank you segfault!  Would you mind showing me how to specify rounding and scale as Java defines them?  Thank you so very much in advance!

Comment: GMP has no support for rounding and scale. You'll have to implement them yourself.